# how to pass value to function from methods in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, vuejs2

how to pass value to function from methods in Vue.js?

I got a value in methods, but I need to pass this value to other function, how could I do it?

```js
methods: {
  getDataSource() {
    let self = this;
    arr.forEach((item) => {
      //debugger;
      let tokens = item.path.replace(/^\/|\/$/g, "").split("/");
      let fid = item.fid;
      let current = tree;
      for (let i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        if (!current[tokens[i]]) {
          current[tokens[i]] = {
            fid: item.fid
          };
        }
        current = current[tokens[i]];
      }
      let ffid = Number(item.fid) + 1;
      //console.log(ffid);
    });
}


function uploadFileChunk(fileData, uploadInfo, destinationDirectory) {
  let self = this;
  //debugger
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    console.log(reader.result);
  }
  reader['readAsDataURL'](fileData);
  return objectProvider.uploadFileChunk(
    fileData,
    uploadInfo,
    destinationDirectory
  );
}
```

I wanna pass ffid value to function uploadFileChunk, how could got ffid values?

Comment: where is this uploadFileChunk defined? is it defined in the same file under the methods section?

Comment: What have you tried? Presumably you'd just call `uploadFileChunk(ffid, someUploadInfo, someDestinationDirectory)`. Does that not work?

Comment: @Amaarrockz that's function out of methods.

Comment: @Phil yse, it's not working, so I cannot use that

Comment: @Amaarrockz it's same file, but not under in methods sections

Comment: How does it _"not work"_? Are there any errors reported? If not, how does it not adhere to your expectations?

Comment: @Phil if I direct call that's function, I cannot got my source data.

Comment: when you direct call, you need to pass everything whatever that's required for that function since you can't access any of the variables from the data section

Answer (score 0):

if both handlers are in the same file then you can send it like

```
methods: {
  getDataSource() {
    let self = this;
    arr.forEach((item) => {
      //debugger;
      let tokens = item.path.replace(/^\/|\/$/g, "").split("/");
      let fid = item.fid;
      let current = tree;
      for (let i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        if (!current[tokens[i]]) {
          current[tokens[i]] = {
            fid: item.fid
          };
        }
        current = current[tokens[i]];
      }
      let ffid = Number(item.fid) + 1;
      //Since that function is defined outside try calling it as below
      uploadFileChunk(ffid); // Note that the upload file Chunk accepts three arguments so make sure you pass the other two as well
    });
}
```

Comment: No, I cannot use that, I'd tried before, if I use that I cannot got the data, I don't why. Because I did not get any error or crash.

Comment: then define it inside methods, what's the problem in that?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the function as a method and use this

```
methods: {
  getDataSource() {
    let self = this;
    arr.forEach((item) => {
      //debugger;
      let tokens = item.path.replace(/^\/|\/$/g, "").split("/");
      let fid = item.fid;
      let current = tree;
      for (let i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        if (!current[tokens[i]]) {
          current[tokens[i]] = {
            fid: item.fid
          };
        }
        current = current[tokens[i]];
      }
      let ffid = Number(item.fid) + 1;
      this.uploadFileChunk(ffid)      
    });

  uploadFileChunk(fileData, uploadInfo, destinationDirectory) {
    let self = this;
    //debugger
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
      console.log(reader.result);
    }
    reader['readAsDataURL'](fileData);
    return objectProvider.uploadFileChunk(
      fileData,
      uploadInfo,
      destinationDirectory
    );
  }
}
```

if you **really** wants to use it as a independent function, i would recommend you to create a helper file and import it

**upload-helpers.js** (The name is up to you)

```
export function uploadFileChunk(fileData, uploadInfo, destinationDirectory) => {
    let self = this;
    //debugger
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
      console.log(reader.result);
    }
    reader['readAsDataURL'](fileData);
    return objectProvider.uploadFileChunk(
      fileData,
      uploadInfo,
      destinationDirectory
    );
  }
```

**In your component Vue**

```
import { uploadFileChunk } from './upload-helpers'

methods: {
  getDataSource() {
    let self = this;
    arr.forEach((item) => {
      //debugger;
      let tokens = item.path.replace(/^\/|\/$/g, "").split("/");
      let fid = item.fid;
      let current = tree;
      for (let i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        if (!current[tokens[i]]) {
          current[tokens[i]] = {
            fid: item.fid
          };
        }
        current = current[tokens[i]];
      }
      let ffid = Number(item.fid) + 1;
      uploadFileChunk(ffid)  
    });
}
```